# Ruby Active Record to array. How do you modify the result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

In my model, I have a function where the resultant array is

```
...#<DailyStat subject: "Auditing Theory", topic: "Audit Planning", item_count: 3, correct_item_count: 0>
#<DailyStat subject: "Auditing Theory", topic: "Audit Reporting", item_count: 2, correct_item_count: 0>
#<DailyStat subject: "Auditing Theory", topic: "Audit Sampling", item_count: 2, correct_item_count: 2>...
```

(DailyStat is a model.)
I need to add a percentage of item_count/correct_item_count for accuracy. How do I convert and add another symbol inside. Here is the current code, which does not work.

```
.select("subject, topic, sum(correct_item_count) as correct_item_count, sum(item_count) as item_count") # can't I just add the computation here
.map{|row| row} # Supposed to convert from AR record to array
.map{|row| 
  row[:accuracy] = row[:correct_item_count]/row[:item_count]
  row
  }
```

Is this approach better, or should I do the computation when I execute the select statement (Which is faster?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to fetch it from SQL. Database is for...data, not computation.

You can easily define such method in DailyStat model, and call it in view or elsewhere whenever you need it.

```
class DailyStat < ActiveRecord::Base
  def accuracy
    return 0 if item_count == 0
    correct_item_count/item_count
  end
end
```

And use it

```
stat = DailyStat.last
state.accuracy 
# There is no SQL involved
```

Comment: Yes this sounds like a more Ruby/Rails way to to do things. I just added a provision for formatting and it's all good. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Computation in sql query will be relatively faster then this .
you can do something like this.

```
select("subject, topic, sum(correct_item_count) as correct_item_count, sum(item_count) as item_count, ((sum(item_count)/sum(correct_item_count))*100) as accuracy_percentage")
```